# Making a Naruto Game in Python

Tags: python

i have been stuck in this problem for a while now,

am trying to make a game where the user is given only 100 number to create a well defined shinobi ( got the name from watch Naruto and i love the series)

so i made my own class attributes. am trying to create a function to store the game inside and trying to make it so if the player uses more than 100 or = 100, the code should stop running but instead the code run even to negative a figure

let me put out the code for understanding ( sorry for my long write up, its actually my first time here)

```
print("ok,  lets beging the game")


import Avatars # importing my own customised class


s = Avatars.Shinobi('naruto', 'uzimaki', 'genin', 100, 50, 70)  # original class attributes

name = input('enter your name: ')

print(f'welcome onboard {name}, so you have to make your own ninja using (1- 100) '

  f'and each time you make a ninja, we minus the number from the 100 you have '

  f'GoodLuck!!')


print(" all you have to do is make a ninja that has 'strength', 'chakra', and 'skill' ")


def game(): # putting everything inside a function

try:
    numb = 100  # the max number given by me to the player
    while numb > 0:
        a = (s.set_skill()) # using the imported class
        a1 = int(a)
        numb -= a
        print('you have ', numb)

        b = (s.set_chakra())  # using the imported class
        b1 = int(b)
        numb -= b
        print(' you have ', numb)

        c = (s.set_strength())  # using the imported class
        c1 = int(c)
        numb -= c
        print('you have', numb)

    if numb < 0:  # using an if statement to cut the game half way, if the user inputs more than 100
        print('you have run out of numbers')

    else:
        print('you still have more numbers to go!!')

except:
    print('enter only number')
```

print(game())

OUTPUT:

```
ok,  lets beging the game


enter your name: emma


welcome onboard emma, so you have to make your own ninja using (1- 100) and each time you make a ninja, we minus the number from the 100 you have GoodLuck!!

all you have to do is make a ninja that has 'strength', 'chakra', and 'skill' 

enter skill rate (1 - 100): 50
you have  50

enter chakra level (1 - 100): 50
you have  0

enter strength level (1 - 100): 60
you have -60

you have run out of numbers
```

the code was suppose to stop, since i have input 50 twice and have no number left

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Hi [Emmanuel Chidera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19112705/emmanuel-chidera), this is happening because you are substracting from `numb` after each set operation but checking `numb` value 'til the end. In order to prevent this to occur, you may check the `numb` variable value after each set operation and if its value is <= 0 you end right there the program execution.

To help you to understand this situation a bit better, I'm going to provide this short code snippet demonstrating the difference between your approach (checking `numb` value at the end) and the possible solution.

```
def initShinobi():
    #This is similar to your approach
    print("Inside initShinobi function\n")

    maxPoints = 100 # the maximum stat points 

    skill = int(input("Enter skill level: "))
    maxPoints -= skill
    print(f'You have {maxPoints} points left to assign.')

    chakra = int(input("Enter chakra level: "))
    maxPoints -= chakra
    print(f'You have {maxPoints} points left to assign.')

    strength = int(input("Enter strength level: "))
    maxPoints -= strength
    print(f'You have {maxPoints} points left to assign.')

    if maxPoints < 0:
        print('you have run out of numbers')


def haveAvailablePoints(points):
    """Helper function to check your available points"""
    if points > 0:
        print(f'You have {points} points left to assign.')
        return True
    else:
        print('You have run out of points')
        return False


def initShinobi2():
    # This is the possible solution
    print("\n\nInside initShinobi2 function\n")

    maxPoints = 100 # the maximum stat points 

    skill = int(input("Enter skill level: "))
    maxPoints -= skill

    if not haveAvailablePoints(maxPoints):
        return          

    chakra = int(input("Enter chakra level: "))
    maxPoints -= chakra
    
    if not haveAvailablePoints(maxPoints):
        return  

    strength = int(input("Enter strength level: "))
    maxPoints -= strength

    if not haveAvailablePoints(maxPoints):
        return
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    initShinobi()
    initShinobi2()
```

Assuming skill = 50, chakra = 50 and strength = 60 the code snippet above produces this output:

```
Inside initShinobi function

Enter skill level: 50
You have 50 points left to assign.
Enter chakra level: 50
You have 0 points left to assign.
Enter strength level: 60
You have -60 points left to assign.
you have run out of numbers


Inside initShinobi2 function

Enter skill level: 50
You have 50 points left to assign.
Enter chakra level: 50
You have run out of points
Successful execution. Press Enter to exit...
```

As you can see, in `initShinobi2` function after I entered skill and chakra level it won't ask for me to enter the strength level since we have reached the maximum value with the first two parameters.

**Note:** You may notice in `initShinobi2` function that if you type skill = 50 and chakra = 60 the output will be similar to the demonstration here but logically it has overpassed the maximum value, but that's something that I delegate you to solve.